# Android bitmap stretched?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I have an application, where you can take a picture, and then you display it as a background of the relative layout. But somehow the image is get stretched in a strange way, maybe forced in landscape mode (?). I don't know how to rotate it in the correct way, here's my code.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/1.jpg";
        File image = new File(filePath);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);

        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout1.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

[image: This is how I take my picture]

[image: And this is how I get the result in my layout background, the image is streched, and not look like my taken image.]

My first picture is the original one, and the second is the streched that I get in my layout.

How to solve this problem? What I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `RelativeLayout` has a different aspect ratio than the image. Setting an image as the background of a view doesn't give you any real scaling options, it just stretches the image to fit the view. Instead you should put an `ImageView` inside your `RelativeLayout` (declare it first so it's behind all the other views) and set the image content of that view (**not** the background). Make sure to use an appropriate `scaleType`; in this case I chose `centerCrop`, which will scale the image such that both the width and height are at least as large as the corresponding dimension of the `ImageView`.

```
<RelativeLayout ... >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <!-- other views -->

</RelativeLayout>

ImageView backgroundImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_image);
...
// after taking a picture
backgroundImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can but if you move the image to an image layer on top of the layout you can just set scale type to fit center and it won't stretch. 
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
or

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scaleType="center"/>
```